# *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x926d620 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting, nsautoreleasepool

My application is ARC enabled one.

In the app delegate i have written a code

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(initializeAnimationImageArrays) withObject:nil];
```

And my method is

```
- (void)initializeAnimationImageArrays
{
    NSArray *animationArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
           nil];
}
```

I have seen some error messages as given below

`*** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x926d620 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking`

I fixed this issue by modifying the method as below.

```
@autoreleasepool
{ 
   NSArray *animationArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
          [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
          [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
          [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
          nil];
}
```

Can anyone please explain to me, what is happening in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says you do not have an autorelease pool to manage autoreleased objects. 
By default, main thread will have its autorelease pool.
When you create a thread you have to create an autorelease pool on your own.

Comment: I found this problem in ipad 4.3 simulator.In 5.0 and 5.1 there is no problem.

Comment: Interesting. Let's find out what has been added in IOS to eliminate the warning.